# Get the list of figures in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to:

```
pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(x)
pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(y)
# ...
for i, figure in enumerate(pylab.MagicFunctionReturnsListOfAllFigures()):
  figure.savefig('figure%d.png' % i)
```

What is the magic function that returns a list of current figures in pylab?

Websearch didn't help...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Pyplot has [get_fignums](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=gcf#matplotlib.pyplot.get_fignums) method that returns a list of figure numbers. This should do what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
y = -x

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(y)

for i in plt.get_fignums():
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.savefig('figure%d.png' % i)
```

Comment: There is also now a `plt.get_figlabels` method that can be used in the same way, I used that to include the figure label in the filename on saving it.

Answer (score 29):

The following one-liner retrieves the list of existing figures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figs = list(map(plt.figure, plt.get_fignums()))
```

Comment: Easily the best answer.

Answer (score 17):

### Edit: As [Matti Pastell's solution shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15900439/190597), there is a much better way: use `plt.get_fignums()`.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import matplotlib._pylab_helpers

x=np.random.random((10,10))
y=np.random.random((10,10))
pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(x)
pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(y)

figures=[manager.canvas.figure
         for manager in matplotlib._pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_all_fig_managers()]
print(figures)

# [<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0xb788ac6c>, <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0xa143d0c>]

for i, figure in enumerate(figures):
    figure.savefig('figure%d.png' % i)
```

Comment: Sure it works, but the underscore in the beginning of _pylab_helpers is a signal that this is not a supported interface and may go away at any time. If there is no published interface and you have a use case for one, please file a feature request.

Comment: @Jouni I've run into the same problem and would like to do just that. Unfortunately the whole host of matplotlib/pyplot/pylab websites isn't all that clear to me. Could you indicate where I could file a feature request? Github?

Comment: Yes, Github (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) or possibly on the mailing list (http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general).

Comment: If you're going to use `_pylab_helpers` you can do `_pylab_helpers.Gcf.figs.values()` which is easier. But yeah, uses internal variables etc, so use Matti's way if you don't mind non-OO interface.

Answer (score 3):

This should help you (from the pylab.figure doc):

> call signature::
>
> figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6),
>   dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
>
> **Create a new figure and return a
>   :class:`matplotlib.figure.Figure`
>   instance.**  If *num* = *None*, the
>   figure number will be incremented and
>   a new figure will be created.**  The
>   returned figure objects have a
>   *number* attribute holding this number.

If you want to recall your figures in a loop then a good aproach would be to store your figure instances in a list and to call them in the loop.

```
>> f = pylab.figure()
>> mylist.append(f)
etc...
>> for fig in mylist:
>>     fig.savefig()
```

Comment: "The returned figure objects have a _number_ attribute holding this number." Thanks. That's what I was looking for and missed it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't manually specified `num` in any of your figure constructors (so all of your figure numbers are consecutive) and all of the figures that you would like to save actually have things plotted on them...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plot_some_stuff()
# find all figures
figures = []
for i in range(maximum_number_of_possible_figures):
    fig = plt.figure(i)
    if fig.axes:
        figures.append(fig)
    else:
        break
```

Has the side effect of creating a new blank figure, but better if you don't want to rely on an unsupported interface

Answer (score 2):

I tend to name my figures using strings rather than using the default (and non-descriptive) integer. Here is a way to retrieve that name and save your figures with a descriptive filename:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figures = []
figures.append(plt.figure(num='map'))
# Make a bunch of figures ...
assert figures[0].get_label() == 'map'

for figure in figures:
    figure.savefig('{0}.png'.format(figure.get_label()))
```