# How to save matplotlib plots to a list, then display them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am running Python, and I am creating a series of histograms in a for-loop like this:

```
hist_dict = {}

for data, name in zip([mon, tue, wed, thu, fri], 
['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']):
    plt.figure()
    plt.title("Call Distribution for " + name)
    plt.xlabel("Number of Daily Calls")
    plt.ylabel("Number of Days")
    plt.xlim(0, 1200)
    hist_dict[name] = plt.hist(data, bins=24)
```

Once the images are saved to my dictionary (or a list, I don't know if it matters), can I call them and show them?  I have tried

```
hist_dict["Monday"].show()
plt.show(hist_dict["Monday"])
hist_dict["Monday"]
```

and nothing seems to work.  If this doesn't work, what is the best way to save plots locally (not as a png file) so that I can arrange into a subplot setup?

Comment: Try following the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783217/get-the-list-of-figures-in-matplotlib). Plot everything without showing and then iterate using `plt.get_fignums():` and show/save them

Comment: If this question is being asked with the premise to use its answer for creating subplots, that's not going to work. Subplots are always part of a figure and shouldn't be moved around. You would hence rather create the plot you want plotting to an axes (a subplot) when necessary.