# Plotting list of figure numbers in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I intend to plot 3 figures in one jpeg or png file by enumerating a list. How do I save the plots of the list of existing figure numbers obtained using a code similar to one shown here: [Get the list of figures in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783217/get-the-list-of-figures-in-matplotlib), and below. The link shows how to save each figure separately but not saving as one image from the list of figure numbers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = list(map(plt.figure, plt.get_fignums()))
```

My wish is to get the 3 plots represented in the list of figure numbers as one jpeg file

Comment: That's not possibly with matplotlib. But you can of course create 3 separate jpg files and then use a some imaging tool, e.g. pillow,  to [concatenate those into a single jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python)).

Comment: Okay thanks. I just looked here https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter17/. so you think the cat command of pillow will work for my use case.